# How to fix error related to JSON parse in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, elixir-jason

I am new to using vba/macro and trying to link data from FRED. I will shamelessly admit, I got the codes from chatgpt. I tried running it but got a message saying "can't execute code in break mode" and "Set xmlDoc = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlHttp.responseText)" seems to be the error. I've never written a code before so if you guys can explain how to fix it in plain language that would be super helpful. Thanks!

```
Sub GetDataFromFRED()
    Dim myURL As String
    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim xmlDoc As Object
    Dim dataRange As Range

    'Specify the FRED URL for the data you want to retrieve
    myURL = "https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id=GNPCA&api_key=6b1194d42ad5b4543a08d7da990bacd4&file_type=json"

    'Create a new XML HTTP request object
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
    xmlHttp.send

    'Parse the response as JSON
    
    Set xmlDoc = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlHttp.responseText)

    'Specify where you want to paste the data in Excel
    Set dataRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    'Paste the data into Excel
    dataRange.Value = xmlDoc("observations")(1)("value")
End Sub
```

Googled the error message, JASON error related.

Comment: Did you import the `JsonConverter` bas module from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON  into your workbook?

Comment: and add 'Scripting' lib reference